# Loop colSum over a list of CSV files in R

Tags: r, csv, matrix

Say I have a list of 300 CSV files loaded using:

```
files <- list.files(".../files", pattern=".csv")
```

Each CSV file is a 10x10 matrix and I want to loop over each and every file to determine how many columns inside each CSV in which there are exactly 5 instances of a 1

I'm new to R and I'm not sure how to loop this over every file in my list.

Appreciate any help greatly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to read the data probably with `read.csv` (from `base R`) or use `fread` from `data.table` after looping over the `files` in `lapply`, then get the `colSums`

```
sapply(files, function(x) sum(colSums(read.csv(x) == 1, na.rm = TRUE) == 5))
```

#### data

```
files <- list.files(".../files", pattern="\\.csv", full.names = TRUE)
```